# UnityからAndroidのナビゲーションバーを非表示かつフルスクリーン状態を維持したい

Tags: android, unity3d

UnityからAndroidのナビゲーションバーを非表示にして
フルスクリーンエリアを広げた状態を維持したいのですが
うまくいかず悩んでおります。

下記処理をUnity側で定義して、`setSystemUiVisibility`を呼び出して
FLGをセットしているのですが、画面をタップするとナビゲーションバー
の非表示状態が解除されてしまいます非表示状態を維持するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？
フラグ設定は公式の
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html
を翻訳して、
`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` + `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` +
`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` + `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`　を設定しています。
機種：ARROWS-X F-02E Androidバージョン=4.1.2
●ボタンタップ時呼び出しメソッド

```
using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
    using (var activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(FLG設定メソッド));
    }
}
```

●FLG設定メソッド

```
using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
    using (var activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
        using (var window = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow")) {
            using (var view = window.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDecorView")) {
                view.Call("setSystemUiVisibility", 設定フラグ);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

長文で申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いします。